# Instead of `transform.forward` go back

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Stay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject movePlatform;
    private void OnTriggerStay()
    {
        movePlatform.transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * 8;
    }
}
```

I am trying to make my object move in the opposite direction, not `forward`. A `backward` doesn't exist in Unity or in C#.

How can I go back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
movePlatform.transform.position -= transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * 8;
```